# How to align excluded list item to page margin?

Tags: html, css

Somebody please help me. I want to align the numbering-excluded HTML list item with the other numbered items.

**Like the following list structure**.

1.List item
2.List item
skipped list item

**NOT THIS**

1. List item
2. List item2
   skipped list item

```css
.caption {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li class="caption">skipped List item</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list-style-position: inside` on list and then you just remove number from specific list item with `list-style-type: none`

```css
ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.caption {
  list-style-type: none; 
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="caption">skipped list item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You can also use `:nth-child(<index of element>)` instead of a class. Information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Thank you. That really helped!!